FIRST and LAST VALUE bringing conflicting row quantities in the same query. WHY?
I have a SQL query with the objective to extract the values of the row with the last date for each different value that exists in column_2.
I used the window function on all the columns that might have a variation in values, trying to ensure that I got the most recent ones. Column_3 and column_4 are always the same for each element in column_2.
DECLARE _timestamp TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE _timestamp_start TIMESTAMP;

SET _timestamp = TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), HOUR), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
SET _timestamp_start = TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), HOUR), INTERVAL 24 HOUR);


SELECT DISTINCT
    FIRST_VALUE(day) OVER (PARTITION BY column_2 ORDER BY day DESC) as day_last_value,
    column_2,
    column_3,
    column_4,
    FIRST_VALUE(xxx) OVER (PARTITION BY column_2 ORDER BY day DESC) as xxx_last_value,
    FIRST_VALUE(yyy) OVER (PARTITION BY column_2 ORDER BY day DESC) as yyy_last_value,
    FIRST_VALUE(zzz) OVER (PARTITION BY column_2 ORDER BY day DESC) as zzz_last_value,
  FROM 
    table1
  WHERE 
    day BETWEEN DATE(_timestamp_start) AND DATE(_timestamp)

What I'm finding very strange is that I had to set up the query with FIRST_VALUE and DESC order to get to the line with the last date.
That's because by changing to LAST_VALUE and ASC order it's resulting twice as many lines... It is not retrieving the results for only one day for each element in column_2, as it should.
My expectation was that the number of rows would be the same.

The default frame is rows between unbounded preceding and current row. If you add rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following to last_value(...) over (partition by ... order by ... rows between ...) it should work.

Perhaps, you have several rows by the same day. Then order of rows in window over(... order by day) unpredictable.

@shawnt00 The default is range unbounded preceding not rows unbounded preceding (subtly different), which is probably the issue here. But without sample data we cannot tell.

Yes, the default is technically range between unbounded preceding and current row. With current row it's relevant to note for sure--if not logically then for query performance. When the goal is to rope in all the data with both ends unbounded they are equivalent and I don't think the query plan will be impacted either. I can't readily find a citation that indicates any reason to favor one over the other although I'm curious if the standard addressed this.

Thank you all so much!
I didn't know about this window frame clause. I've studied it now and what you've said makes sense. Adding the modified clause (compared to the default) worked.

Using window function and distinct is a bad practice. What you really want to do is grouping by column_2 and aggregate others using this column.
If column_3 and 4 are always same for column_2, you can aggregate using min / max or any_value.
To get first and last value, you can use MIN_BY and MAX_BY functions.
You can find more details about this function here
SELECT
    column_2,
    MAX(day) as day_last_value,
    ANY_VALUE(column_3) as column_3,
    ANY_VALUE(column_4) as column_4,
    MAX_BY(xxx, day) as xxx_last_value,
    MAX_BY(yyy, day) as yyy_last_value,
    MAX_BY(zzz, day) as zzz_last_value,
FROM 
    table1
WHERE 
    day BETWEEN DATE(_timestamp_start) AND DATE(_timestamp)


Thank you so much! It worked!
But I'd like to know something: why using window function and distinct is a bad practice?

Window functions' purpose is to derive information for all the table. On the other hand, you want to aggregate data based on column_2, which brings us to group by instead of window functions. Also, distinct is a signal of doing something wrong. Most people using distinct to deduplicate data, which means the wrong aggregation level is used in the query.
